# Laravel and unique slugs

Tags: php, laravel-4, slug

I'm trying to generate an get unique slugs, just like MyBB does, but it doens't work well...

I'm using the plugin `https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/tree/2.x` for `Laravel 4.2`.

So I got this:

```
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

class ForumController extends \BaseController implements SluggableInterface {

    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'title',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
    ];
```

And in that Class, I don't know how I need to generate the slug,
it needs to be generated in this function:

```
public function PostTopic($cid)
    {
        //Get all the data and store it inside Store Variable

        $data = Input::all();

        // Make's messages of faults
        $messages = array(
           'title.required'     => 'U moet een titel opgeven!',
           'titel.unique'       => 'De opgegeven titel bestaat al, gebruik een andere.',
           'message.required'   => 'u moet een bericht opgeven!',
           'spamprt'            => 'honeypot', //spam protection
           'time'               => 'required|honeytime:60'
        );

        $rules = array(
            'title' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
            );

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);

        //process the storage
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->with('errors', $validator->errors())->withInput();
        }else{

            //store
            $thread                     = new Thread;
            $thread->cid                = $cid;
            $thread->title              = Input::get('title');
            $thread->message            = Input::get('message');
            $thread->prefix             = 0;
            $thread->uid                = Auth::id();
            $thread->username           = Auth::user()->username;
            $thread->date_posted        = Carbon\Carbon::now();
            $thread->save();
            Session::put('_token', sha1(microtime()));
            //redirect
            return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Uw bericht is succesvol geplaatst!');
            }
    }
```

But how? And how do I need to get the slugs to display them in an URL or so?